# Inline CSS vs New FIle

Tags: css, sass, frontend

I have worked the majority of my time as developer in smaller projects and I just started a job with a bigger enterprise. I am working primarily in the front end. We use a design system and Bootstrap for styling. I am working in a small fix that requires a few lines of custom css (about 20). Should I make a new file, or is it okay to place them inline? I have been reluctant to use inline styles in the past because it can get a bit messy but I am not sure what is the best decision here?

Comment: Surely the people you should be asking are your colleagues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever heard of microservices ? The idea is separate the project in small and independent parts make it easier to maintain.

Think about it and maybe you will realize that separated files is a better option

Comment: Thank you! This is along the lines of what I had in mind, I just needed some confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

If your custom CSS code is being used for many time, you can make a separate file for your custom CSS code. And for non-reusable code you can use inline pattern.

I usually work with both. But I would like to make a separate file for custom CSS code.